# Why doesn’t add a div bottom of another div in sending email?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, email, easendmail

I'd want add a div to the bottom of another div. I have tested this code and it works fine.

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 200px; height: 150px;">
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: 50px; border: 1px solid red;">
</div>
</div>
```

But when I use this as a template for sending an email , it doesn’t work. When I check css code in firebug only this styles doesn’t set (just : position:absolute;bottom:0; and position:relative;) but another css style add.
I use easendmail for sending mail.
What is problem?

Comment: What mail client are you viewing this in?

Comment: I test in yahoo mail and gmail.

Comment: I believe gmail has a problem with `position: absolute`.

Comment: I would not use position absolute if I were you.

Comment: Show a jpg/png what your email looks like, and what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Email has very limited [CSS support](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/), in fact I would never use the position attribute at all.

I'd also avoid div's in favor of tables. Email is very different to web, so you should do some research before getting too deep into trouble with things not working.

Here are 3 resources to get you up to speed:

http://www.reachcustomersonline.com/how-to-code-html-email-newsletters-all-new-version/

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/guidelines/

http://www.sitepoint.com/code-html-email-newsletters/